# How to let title number include seperated text boxes?

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, numbering

I am writing my thesis and headers are numbered like 1.2 or 1.2.1 etc which is a pretty easy thing to set.

But when my header 1 is set in a textbox, the counting does not include this header anymore.

add into

- The Textbox is a 'simple white textbox' and comes from the 'insert'
  tab.
- I had put the existing heading numbering to the header in the textbox

Image below shows what I mean

[image: example]

How do I make my default Word chapter numbering include these headings in seperated textboxes?

What I have tried so far:

- Working with fields
- Manually setting the multiple level list counting (flopped twice, conflicts with word's own header numbering?)

Comment: What kind of textboxes are on your document? Were they inserted from the Insert or Developer tab? Do you insert the numbering in the textboxes after they have been created on the other pages? Can you add a better image that show the numbering/heading on both pages (the page with the textbox and without)

Comment: I have edited the question to answer your questions, thank you.
I have removed all forms of numbering at the headers because it got messed up too much. Therefor I am not able to make a more representitive image than the one I have here.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make my default Word chapter numbering include these headings in seperated textboxes?

you can NOT.

The flow of structured text (= with headings) in Document need to be linear, which includes only standard text. Text box is not linear (it's not clear what part of the document is earlier / later) you can't put heading there.

Comment: Ok clear, now I will just use tabs and a lot of 'enters' to get the title to the right position instead of adding a seperated textbox. It's messy but appearantly the only way to go then

Comment: Or, I could set the header numbering manually. Either way it seems like a messy solution unfortunatly

Comment: "I will just use tabs and a lot of 'enters' " - why would you need to do so? Do you need to place headers to top of page? You can added manual page break before, or change paragraph settings (https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/control-pagination-e9b3b005-cf62-41d0-afa2-24cfb223ab42?ui=en-us&rs=en-ie&ad=ie). Do you need to align it right? Just right align paragraph.

Comment: I mean to have the header, in this case the "3" at the right place without the usage of textbox. In my experience with Word I can only perform this with tabs and enters. Why would I need a page break to set the position of that '3' ?

Comment: The position where the '3' is in the attached image

Comment: Isn't that just right aligned? I still can't see why would you need enters and tabs to achieve that.

Comment: Right aligned is one step, vertical alignment does not respond in Word on selected text so I need a few dozen of Enters